# Python broadcasting updated Web-socket data in a thread class function

Tags: python, html, json, multithreading, websocket

I created a simple python web-socket server like following

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
import threading
import queue
import time
import logging


logging.basicConfig()

STATE = {"value": 0}

USERS = set()

msg_queue = queue.Queue(256)
def state_event():
    return json.dumps({"type": "state", **STATE})


def users_event():
    return json.dumps({"type": "users", "count": len(USERS)})


async def notify_state():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = state_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def notify_users():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = users_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def register(websocket):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def unregister(websocket):
    USERS.remove(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def counter(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await websocket.send(state_event())
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data["action"] == "minus":
                STATE["value"] -= 1
                await notify_state()
            elif data["action"] == "plus":
                STATE["value"] += 1
                await notify_state()
            else:
                logging.error("unsupported event: {}", data)
    finally:
        await unregister(websocket)

class clsSerialThread(threading.Thread):  
    global STATE    
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, job_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.job_queue = job_queue

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            time.sleep(10)
            #broadcast an updated value every 10 seconds
            for ws in USERS: 
                asyncio.create_task(ws.send(json.dumps({"value": STATE["value"]+10})))
                   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        serial_thread = clsSerialThread(1, 'Serial', msg_queue)
        serial_thread.setDaemon(True)
        serial_thread.start()
    except Exception as e1:
        print("error communicating to mainboard ...: " + str(e1))

    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets.serve(counter, "localhost", "8081"))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Testing my server using a HTML client as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebSocket demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="minus button">-</div>
            <div class="value">?</div>
            <div class="plus button">+</div>
        </div>
        <div class="state">
            <span class="users">?</span> online
        </div>
        <script>
            var minus = document.querySelector('.minus'),
                plus = document.querySelector('.plus'),
                value = document.querySelector('.value'),
                users = document.querySelector('.users'),
                websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8081/");
            minus.onclick = function (event) {
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify({action: 'minus'}));
            }
            plus.onclick = function (event) {
                websocket.send(JSON.stringify({action: 'plus'}));
            }
            websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
                data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                switch (data.type) {
                    case 'state':
                        value.textContent = data.value;
                        break;
                    case 'users':
                        users.textContent = (
                            data.count.toString() + " user" +
                            (data.count == 1 ? "" : "s"));
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.error(
                            "unsupported event", data);
                }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, the run function keep throwing out error like "Exception has occurred: RuntimeError no running event loop"

How do I update the web-socket data inside the thread run function? I added the async keyword to the function, it did not help

Answer (score 0):

I found out that an event loop global instance needs to be shared to the thread class as following:

```
import asyncio
import json
import websockets
import threading
import queue
import time
import logging


logging.basicConfig()

STATE = {"value": 0}

USERS = set()

msg_queue = queue.Queue(256)

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

delay = 5
def state_event():
    global STATE
    STATE["value"] += delay
    return json.dumps({"type": "state", **STATE})


def users_event():
    return json.dumps({"type": "users", "count": len(USERS)})


async def notify_state():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = state_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def notify_users():
    if USERS:  # asyncio.wait doesn't accept an empty list
        message = users_event()
        await asyncio.wait([user.send(message) for user in USERS])


async def register(websocket):
    USERS.add(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def unregister(websocket):
    USERS.remove(websocket)
    await notify_users()


async def counter(websocket, path):
    # register(websocket) sends user_event() to websocket
    await register(websocket)
    try:
        await websocket.send(state_event())
        async for message in websocket:
            data = json.loads(message)
            if data["action"] == "minus":
                STATE["value"] -= 1
                await notify_state()
            elif data["action"] == "plus":
                STATE["value"] += 1
                await notify_state()
            else:
                logging.error("unsupported event: {}", data)
    finally:
        await unregister(websocket)

class clsSerialThread(threading.Thread):  
    global STATE
    global loop    
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, job_queue):
        super().__init__()
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.job_queue = job_queue

    def run(self):
        while(True):
            time.sleep(delay)
            #broadcast an updated value every 'delay' seconds
            loop.create_task(notify_state())
                   
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        serial_thread = clsSerialThread(1, 'Serial', msg_queue)
        serial_thread.setDaemon(True)
        serial_thread.start()
    except Exception as e1:
        print("error communicating to mainboard ...: " + str(e1))

    loop.run_until_complete(websockets.serve(counter, "localhost", "8081"))
    loop.run_forever()
```

it seems like the broadcasting update is being call periodically now, but the websocket client web page's update frequency does not seem to match the delay setting. Is there a way to improve the latency?